# How to pass JSON string as array

Tags: c#, arrays, json

```
[
    {"id": 1, "name": "danny_devito", "img": "/images/1"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "jim_carey", "img": "/images/2"},
    {"id": 3, "name": "tyler_1", "img": "/images/3"}
]
```

```
 [System.Serializable]
    public class Players {
        public int id;
        public string name;
        public string img;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class PlayersArray {
        public Players[] playersData;
    }
```

```
string playersJson = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/playersFile.json");
        PlayersArray loadedPlayerData = (PlayersArray)JsonUtility.FromJson<PlayersArray>(playersJson);

        Debug.Log("Danny Boy: " + loadedPlayerData.playersData[0].name);
```

I followed tons of tutorials and none of it works!

It gives me this error:

[image: it gives me this error]

Comment: Your JSON is array, but PlayersArray is object.

Comment: This is `JsonUtility` from [tag:unity3d], right?  If so I don't think `JsonUtility.FromJson()` supports arrays as root containers, you may need to add some wrapper object.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36244111/3744182) by [Programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3785314/programmer) to [Serialize and Deserialize Json and Json Array in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36239705/3744182).  In fact I think your question is a duplicate, agree?

Comment: Alternatively, as noted in the answer above, Json.NET is now officially supported by Unity, you may get it from here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@3.0/manual/index.html.  With Json.NET you can do `var players = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Player>>(playersJson);`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to deserialize an object.  But the JSON you show isn't an object.  It's an array.  Deserialize it into a collection:

```
var loadedPlayerData = JsonUtility.FromJson<List<Players>>(playersJson);
```

Or even just an array:

```
var loadedPlayerData = JsonUtility.FromJson<Players[]>(playersJson);
```

As an aside... Names are important.  `Players` is a misleading name for *a player*.  The class should be called `Player` instead.

---

Additionally, this class *might* not deserialize at all, depending on how the JSON serializer works.  They tend to use *properties*, not *fields*.  You'll likely want to use properties anyway:

```
public class Players {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string img { get; set; }
}
```

For further improvements, you will probably also want to capitalize the property names.  The JSON serializer *might* be case-sensitive (I don't think they tend to be by default, but it's worth testing) and you may need to add attributes to the properties to specify their names in the JSON.  But just to get the code *working*, at the very least you'll most likely need properties here instead of fields.